# Kerberos IE6 Windows 2000

Tags: windows, iis, authentication, kerberos, internet-explorer

Kerberos works on Windows XP with IE 7 and 8, but a client who is on Windows 2000 with IE 6 can not authenticate with Kerberos. The Windows Server 2003 shows authentication as NTLM.

The web application is running on port 40000 with its own app pool.

How can I get IE 6 to authenticate with Kerberos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue. I found the answer [Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299838)

The option under **tools** > **Advanced** > **Enable Integrated Windows Authentication (requires restart)** check box in the Security  section was not checked. This looks not be set by default for our network.